# What does question mark do in php?

Tags: php, php-8.1

```
class Service
{
    private Logger $logger;

    public function __construct(
        ?Logger $logger = null,
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger ?? new NullLogger();
    }
}
```

I'm learning php oop.

What does question mark do in `?Logger $logger = null`??

I googled but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: in short take a look at the [documents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)

Answer (score 0):

"?" in front of argument or property means that this argument/property is nullabe, in your example you can pass either a Logger object or null.

You can read more about it here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Answer (score 0):

This is `Nullable type`.

[PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.nullable)